# Braintree shipping/billing

Tags: javascript, php, braintree

I have discussed this with Braintree support a bit, but still not finding an exact answer/solution.  I have Braintree gateway working with js/php...able to process a payment with one touch.  Also have it sending some of the info back through zapier to infusionsoft, but trying to pass shipping and billing, and everything I have tried doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is it possible?

My form:

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="checkout_bt.php">
  <p><div id="paypal-container"></div></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_address_line1" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_address_line2" value="">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Pay"></p>
</form>


<script src='https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js'></script>
<script>

  braintree.setup(
    '<?php echo $btClientToken; ?>', 
    'paypal', {

     container: "paypal-container",

    singleUse: true,
    amount: .01,
    currency: 'USD',
    enableShippingAddress: 'true',
    enableBillingAddress: 'true',


    onPaymentMethodReceived: function (details) {
        // Post these values to your server
   $('#checkout').append("<input type='hidden' name='billing_address_line1' value='" + details.billing.streeAddress+ "'></input>");
   $('#checkout').append("<input type='hidden' name='billing_address_line2' value='" + details.billingAddress.line2 + "'></input>");
   $('#checkout').append("<input type='hidden' name='billing_address_city' value='" + details.billingAddress.city + "'></input>");
   $('#checkout').append("<input type='hidden' name='billing_address_state' value='" + details.billingAddress.state + "'></input>");
   $('#checkout').append("<input type='hidden' name='billing_address_postalCode' value='" + details.billingAddress.postalCode + "'></input>");
   $('#checkout').append("<input type='hidden' name='billing_address_countryCode' value='" + details.billingAddress.countryCode + "'></input>");
        // etc ( for any other variables )
      }


    });

</script>
```

...and then there is the receiving end of it as well (I've tried several ways...this one I'm just trying to pass billing street address.....

```
$nonce = $_POST['payment_method_nonce'];
$amount = .01;

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'orderId' => $orderId,
  'amount' => $amount,
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
    'billing' => [ 'streetAddress' => '1 E Main St'],
  'options' => array(
  'addBillingAddressToPaymentMethod' => true,
  'submitForSettlement' => true
  )
));
```

Comment: It looks like your property names don't meet [PayPal's billing address requirements](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#address-object). As specified in [Braintree's documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal#billing-address), you also may need to contact PayPal in order to retrieve billing addresses using `onPaymentMethodReceived`. If neither of these resolve your issue you should continue talking with [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up...realized on Friday about having to enable receiving shipping/billing info from paypal for onPaymentMethodsReceived from tech support...suppose to be released in the next 24-72 hours.  Thanks!